# Mathematical Induction, Want to check I'm getting this right

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

I just want to make sure i'm doing this right for other questions. i have a question: 
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j(j+1)} =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ and have to show that the function $$f(n) = \frac{n}{n+1}$$ applies for all n in **N**. so it's the same setup right? where i do the n =1. then assume that it's true for n and prove that its true for n + 1 by simply saying $$\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$ right?

Comment: what is the index of your sum?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner (1/1*2) + (1/2*3) + (1/3*4)+ ... + (1/n*(n+1))

Comment: And I think, the equal sign must be removed

Comment: An easier way to prove the value of the sum : Consider $\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{j+1}=\frac{1}{j(j+1)}$ ; nearly all terms cancel out! But the idea how to apply the induction is correct. You add the $n+1$th summand, namely $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ and you must get $\frac{n+1}{n+2}$ as you mentioned

Comment: What's inside the $\sum$?????

Comment: You don't "simply say".  Show that it is true in the base case.  Assume that is it true for some value $k$.  Show that when it is true for $k$ it must also be true for $k+1$  By the way, you are confusing $n's$ and $j's$ in your set-up.

Comment: @barakmanos i've edited it to resemble the quesiton

Answer (score 1):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{1+1}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1+1)}=$

$\color\red{\frac{n}{n+1}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1+1)}=$

$\frac{n+1}{n+1+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: @Jim Derkin: Why did you unaccept my answer???